# design winform C# visual studio 2010 lost position elements

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i have problem with design winforms.
on Windows XP and the same visual studio 2010 everything is fine.
on Windows 7 I have shifted components and some elements are smaller.
service pack 1 visual studio 2010 does not help.
is there a fix for this bug?
I have to build in options to set something?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This issue is some kind of `DPI related issue`. Is your form's `AutoScaleMode` `AutoScaleMode.Font`?

Comment: Definitely DPI-related. In Windows 7, the default DPI is set according to your screen size. That's not the case back in Windows XP, where it was always 100%. The face and size of the default font also changed, from Tahoma 8pt to Segoe UI 9 pt.

Comment: I found the problem.I have set size text (DPI) 125% in the options screen. but I need 125% to view code ;/

Comment: I have set AutoScaleMode dpi.
Why is this option does not work?